# spring security oauth implementation

Tags: spring-security

I downloaded the sample project from http://spring-security-oauth.codehaus.org/tutorial.html and tried to implement for my trialsite

Below is my dispatched xml

```
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
  <property name="mappings">
    <props>
      <prop key="/oauth/authorization">oauthController</prop>
    </props>
  </property>
  <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="oauthController" class="mypackage.OauthController">
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails"/>
</bean>
```

Below is application context

```
<security:http auto-config='true' access-denied-page="/index.jsp">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/oauth/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />

    <security:form-login authentication-failure-url="/index.jsp" default-target-url="/index.jsp" login-page="/index.jsp" />
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/index.jsp" />
</security:http>

<bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryOAuth2ProviderTokenServices">
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true"/>
</bean>

<oauth:provider client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices" >
    <oauth:verification-code user-approval-page="/oauth/authorization"/>
</oauth:provider>

<oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
    <oauth:client clientId="client1" authorizedGrantTypes="authorization_code"/>
</oauth:client-details-service>
```

After sending request from client as

http://localhost:8080/trialsite/oauth/user/authorize?client_id=client1&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2Ftonr%2Ftrialsite%2Faccess.jsp&response_type=code

i am getting 404 error (resource not found), what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the springservlet dispatcher in web.xml....because the endpoints(oauth/authorize and oauth/token) are handled by spring servlet and also you have to add  and  in your provider.xml page.............

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have the follow configure :

```
<http pattern="/oauth/(users|clients)/.*" request-matcher="regex"
    create-session="stateless" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    use-expressions="true" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/users/([^/].*?)/tokens/.*"
        access="#oauth2.clientHasRole('ROLE_CLIENT') and (hasRole('ROLE_USER') or #oauth2.isClient()) and #oauth2.hasScope('write')"
        method="DELETE" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/users/.*"
        access="#oauth2.clientHasRole('ROLE_CLIENT') and (hasRole('ROLE_USER') or #oauth2.isClient()) and #oauth2.hasScope('read')"
        method="GET" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/clients/.*"
        access="#oauth2.clientHasRole('ROLE_CLIENT') and #oauth2.isClient() and #oauth2.hasScope('read')"
        method="GET" />
    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    <expression-handler ref="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />
</http>
```

Before your  " security:http ... " tag .

And also make sure the user you used have logined in with ROLE_USER .